# Activating nested proof

Tags: coq

I have entered the following code in CoqIde:

```
Require Export Classical. 
Require Export Description. 



Theorem excluded_middle_informative : forall P:Prop, {P} + {~ P}.

Theorem classical_definite_description :
 forall (A : Type) (P : A->Prop), inhabited A ->
{ x : A | (exists! x : A, P x) -> P x }.
```

The message `Nested proofs are not allowed unless you turn option Nested Proofs Allowed on.` is produced. How can I turn on the option Nested Proofs Allowed?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to change the keyword `Theorem` for `excluded_middle_informative` to `Axiom`, since this is what it is (you don't provide a proof for it).